# method can return an error or an array - bad implementation?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I'm reading [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) and there is the statement in it that warns against using a variable with a double purpose, for example:

```
1) If a variable is a number, it contains error code.
2) If a varibale is array, it contains data.
```

And that's exactly what I'm doing in my program with the variable `$text` in the code snippet below:

```
$text = $editor->getTextForLinking($data_array['idText']);
if (Arr::is_array($text)) {
    ...
} else {
    Log::instance()->add(Log::Error, $text);
    $this->response->body("Text can't be retrieved");
}
```

I have access to the method getTextForLinking() so it can be changed. How can it be changed to exclude the undesirable situation with double purpose?

I don't want to use exceptions like this:

```
$text = Array();
try {
    $text = $editor->getTextForLinking($data_array['idText']);
} catch(SomeException $e) {
    Log::instance()->add(Log::Error, $text);
    $this->response->body("Text can't be retrieved");
}
```

Comment: Might sound silly, but why not an empty array?

Comment: Since I wouldn't know if there is no such text in db or some error occured during method execution. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yeah, but that should be shifted to the method itself. Providing the same return type helps for consistency, so you always know you get an array (empty or not) - if there's no text, or there's an error, it's the function's duty to handle the appropriate case internally.

Comment: Thanks, I had thought of that and maybe that's the road to go. What about always returning an integer as a result (0=success, !=0 failure) and passing some array variable by reference for the method to put text in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its clear that if anything returned by `getTextForLinking()`, that is not an array, should be considered an error (logged) - So I'm not entirely convinced that your example warrants such a change.

With that said it might be an improvement to keep the return signature of the function the same data `type` (array) regardless of what data you send it. This way it will be consistent (you loose the need for `$text = Array();`) and you wont have to make special cases depending on if its an error or not.

```
$results = $editor->getTextForLinking($data_array['idText']);
if (empty($results)) { 
  Log::instance()->add(Log::Error, $data_array['idText']);
} else {
  // Handle results array 
}
```

**Update**

If you are setting an error message within the function, this violates the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) - A function/method should only have one job. As far as the `$editor->getTextForLinking()` is concerned it will always return an array of text, not deal with the return of an error.

The error message should depend on the **context** (where the method is used). If at some point an empty array is invalid handle/set the error (message) outside of the function as I have shown above.

Doing it this way allows the `$editor` to be oblivious of the validity of the returned result and could allow you to reuse the function elsewhere where an empty array is *not* considered an error.

Comment: With that implementation how would I know what error occured inside `getTextForLinking()` method if I need to? Is always returning an integer as a result (0=success, !=0 failure) and passing some array variable by reference for the method to put text in a good option?

Comment: Thanks, can you please clarify what function you mean here - _If you are setting an error message within the function_ since I'm logging an error outside of getTextForLinking() method?<br>
And what if an exception occurs during the execution of  getTextForLinking() method - lost connection to DB - should it still return an empty array?

Answer (score 0):

do not check the return value, check on the parameters of your function instead. In other words, modify your `getTextForLinking` function wherein you will have a type checking before processing a result

Example pseudocode :

```
function getTextForLinking($text) {

 if $text is array, 
   process it and return an array containing data

else 
  return an array without data , or empty array.

}
```

Comment: From the question looks like the argument will always be the same (likely a number), it's the return type that changes. In your example you double the problem: you need to check both for the argument and for the result...

Comment: @DamienPirsy, I think we dont need to check for the result, because its understood to return an array, but of no data... And if we need to check it, and if-else statement will suffice.

Comment: I said that because before the edit you wrote "return an array or a null value", which means a different return type. Still, the argument checking is superfluous - looks like it will always be the same